# Preserve indention converting RTF to TXT on OS X

Tags: macos, rtf, textedit

I made a multi-level bulleted list in TextEdit that looks something like:

- foo

  - bar
  - stuff

    - things

However, when I try to convert it to text (via cmd-shift-T, copy and paste, or `textutil`), the result looks more like:

- foo
- bar
- stuff
- things

How can I convert to text but preserve the indention?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using the RTF only outline formatting that a plain text file can't handle. You can create your outline manually with tabs to indent and type the bullets with option 8 and when you convert to plain text you will get the result you are after.

Edit: I was able to preserve formatting by:

1. Install [PlainClip](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/plain-clip/)
2. Shift click to launch Plain Clip and enable "remove trailing spaces and tabs from each line" and "remove invisible control characters"
3. Copy from the RTF file
4. Click on PlainClip
5. Paste in a new RTF file and convert to TXT

Comment: Surely there's a way to use applescript or somesuch to convert the ruler formatting into spaces or tabs, though.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Doesn't do it for me - I still get all of the bullets on the same level.

Comment: Exactly followed the instructions, but failed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it looks like [catdoc](http://wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/) could probably do this. I was hoping that [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) would be able to do it as well, but I don't see any indication that it can either on the website or in the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/antiword), so maybe not.